# Hardware breakpoint in GDB +QEMU missing start_kernel

Tags: kernel, qemu, gdb

I am trying to debug a kernel running on QEMU with GDB.

The kernel has been compiled with these options:

```
CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y
CONFIG_GDB_SCRIPTS=y
```

I launch the kernel in qemu with the following command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage
```

In a separate terminal, I launch GDB from the same path and issue these commands in sequence:

```
 gdb ./vmlinux
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
(gdb) hbreak start_kernel
(gdb) c
```

I did not provide a rootfs, as I am not interested in a full working system as of now, just the kernel. I also tried combinations of hbreak/break.

The kernel just boots and reaches a kernel panic as rootfs cannot be found... expected. I want it to stop at start_kernel and then step through the code.

observation: if I set an immediate breakpoint, it works and stops, but not on             start_kernel / startup_64 / main

Is it possible that qemu is not calling all these functions, or is it being masked in some way?

```
Kernel: 4.13.4 
GDB: GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
GCC: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4    
system: ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

NOTE: This exact same procedure worked with kernel 3.2.93, but does not work with 4.13.4, so I guess some more configurations are needed. I could not find resources online which enabled this debug procedure for kernel 4.0 and up, so as of now I am continuing with 3.2, any and all inputs on this are welcome.

Comment: Here is a minimal highly automated setup that might interest you: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/e8f09a76e6b40f61f4b445a40eb28eb4f36a7392#gdb I tend to automatically solve such problems for you on that repo :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and found the solution from [the linux kernel newbies mailing list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg59708.html).

You should disable *KASLR* in your kernel command line with `nokaslr` option, or disable kernel option *"Randomize the kernel memory sections"* inside *"Processor type and features"* when you build your kernel image.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397939/turning-off-kaslr-to-debug-linux-kernel-using-qemu-and-gdb

Answer (score 0):

Besides 'nokaslr', there are gdbstub bugs in qemu if you are using tcg accelarator. Make sure you have a version with bugs fixed.

Check my patch submissions below:

1. Singlestep bug: https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/qemu-devel/patch/20200221002559.6768-1-changbin.du@gmail.com/
2. Breakpoint bug: https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/qemu-devel/patch/20200124021728.32518-1-changbin.du@gmail.com/